# Hassan Akbar-Zadeh's mathematical legacy

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, soft-question, biography

[Professor Hassan Akbar-Zadeh](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=168281) (Born: March 23, 1928- Iran), a prominent Iranian mathematician has died (March 23, 2020) in Paris after years of research and study. (I'm not sure of the exact dates.)

He has worked with the French National Center for Scientific Research and the Collège de France for many years and was director of research at C.N.R.S., Paris, France.

His famous book is "[Initiation to global Finslerian geometry](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2217721)". He was one of the top students of [André Lichnérowicz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andr%C3%A9_Lichnerowicz).

I am googling days and surprisingly I couldn't find a single webpage or article about him. So I want to ask:

> What do you know about Hassan Akbar-Zadeh's mathematical legacy, biography, etc?

Comment: In all the papers from him I could download the author's address is a personal address, which is unusual (in 1965 in Poissy near Paris, 1987 and later in Paris). The [BNF page](https://data.bnf.fr/fr/15116027/hassan_akbar-zadeh/) claims he was CNRS research director in 2006 but he was then 78 so given the French rules he could only be retired (so emeritus would be plausible anyway). But I'm more inclined to believe, in the absence of other information, that he had no affiliation.

Comment: here is a photograph: https://fr.irna.ir/news/83735754/Disparition-d-un-éminent-mathématicien-iranien-à-Paris-l-ambassadeur

Comment: Thanks for information. I heard that he was nominated for French scientist medal and missed it because he did not want to change his nationality (This medal is given only to the French) and inevitably, the prize was awarded to the Marcel Berger.

Comment: I'm not aware of a "French scientist medal", nor of any French scientific distinction that would be reserved for French people. This looks like a random rumor. I'm not sure that a comparison with Berger's legacy is opportune either.

Comment: I removed the "morality". I just wanted to have a somehow complete bio.

Comment: @YCor: I am not sure what was the prize name. Perhaps it is one of these: Prix Peccot, Collège de France
Prix Maurice Audin
Prix Carrière, Académie des Sciences
Prix Leconte, Académie des Sciences
Prix Gaston Julia.

Comment: None of these is reserved to French people. This story is extremely unlikely.

Comment: Google Scholar lists: [this book](https://www.amazon.fr/Initiation-Global-Finslerian-Geometry-Akbar-Zadeh/dp/0444521062), 91 cit.; "*Sur les espaces de Finsler à courbures sectionnelles constantes*,  Acad. Roy. Belg. Bull. Cl. Sci. 1988, 236 cit.; [Les espaces de Finsler...](http://www.numdam.org/article/ASENS_1963_3_80_1_1_0.pdf), Ann. ENS 1963, 75 cit.; *Espaces à tenseur de Ricci parallèle admettant des tranformations projectives* with R. Couty, Rend. Mat. 1978, 14 quot., and MSN detects 13 cit. for "*Generalized Einstein manifolds*", J. Geom. Phys. 1995. Others are below 10 cit.

Comment: @YCor: What [mathscinet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/) says? I have no access to it.

Comment: I have inquired with one of his students, professor Behroz Bidabad; I'm hoping for some personal reminiscenses.

Comment: MSN gives 47 papers: the 2006 book quoted above with 31 cit., a 2004 CRAS note, the 1995 paper quoted above, and others between 1954 and 1988; 4 have $\ge 6$ citations: those 3 of my previous comment and a 1986 J. Math. Pures Appl. paper. 5 joint publications from 1977 to 1987 with Raymond Couty (1919-2005) who had the same PhD advisor Lichnerowicz 3 years earlier; 3 with [Anna Wegrzynowska](https://www.genealogy.math.ndsu.nodak.edu/id.php?id=60454) (the latter published 8 papers between 1970 and 1979), and 1 with [Edmond Bonan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmond_Bonan) in 1964.

Comment: @abx Actually the Prix Audin is nationality-restricted: two prices are given one to an Algerian mathematician working in Algeria and one to a French mathematician working in France.  (voir https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prix_de_mathématiques_Maurice-Audin)

Comment: Abstracts of some of his publications are here: https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/2010478429_H_Akbar-Zadeh

Comment: One of his frequent collaborators was <a href='https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Couty'>Raymond Couty</a>, who was also the department head at the University of Limoges for a number of years. May be you can get some information from that university?

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill actually according to this page, the prize Audin existed from 1958 to 1963 and then since 2004, and you're quoting the rules since 2004 (it says "working in France", which is not a nationality restriction). But it seems quite distinct with the 1958-1963 prize which is obviously the one in consideration (since Berger got it in 1962).

Comment: Anyway Berger got the Audin prize in 1962, eight years after his PhD with Lichnerowicz, he had 17 published papers (including 9 CRAS) $\le 1961$ and 5 more in 1962, while Akbar-Zadeh had still not completed his PhD (1963) — he still had 6 publications $\le 1961$, all CRAS notes of 3-4 pages; his first longer paper was published in 1963 and refers to his thesis. Anyway they looked, at that time, clearly not in the same level of carrier even if Akbar-Zadeh was only 1 year younger.

Comment: @YCor what it says is "un mathématicien français exerçant en France," but I agree that this is for the new version of the prize since 2004.  Anyway, I'm in no way suggesting that Berger (whom I admire and whose work I use regularly) was undeserving of the award.  I was simply pointing out that there are mathematical prizes in France for which being French is a requirement.

Comment: @JoséFigueroa-O'Farrill: I admire his works and life also and my intention was not to make him look unworthy of this (and other) award.

Comment: Without going into prizes or nationalities (what's the point?): his paper "Les espaces de Finsler et certaines de leurs généralisations (1963)" was for some time the best place to understand the connections related to Finsler spaces. He made the jump between Cartan style exposition and the modern understanding of (Kozsul) connections. Moreover, his theorem that a compact Finsler space with constant negative curvature (resp. zero curvature)  is Riemannian (resp. locally isometric to a normed space) is still one of the prettiest theorems in the subject.